# How to display the rows and columns in a table layout in Android

Tags: android, rows, android-tablelayout

I am new to android.I want to display the table layout rows and columns that is displaying its horizontal and its vertical lines of a table layout can any one help me how to do it please.

Answer (score -1):

You should make use of TableLayout in your xml file.
One of the most simple tutorial would be found at 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/grid.html